# Why bash script is not running under php?

Tags: php, bash

I have script sh when i sending data to ttyUSB0

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "AT+CMGF=1" > /dev/ttyUSB0
echo "AT+CMGS=\"+0099887766\"" > /dev/ttyUSB0
echo "test message\032" > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

when i run `> sh test.sh` is ok and i got sms but when i hit the php script

```
<?php
    shell_exec("sh test.sh ");
?>
```

Nothing happen. Bash script and index.php are in `/var/www/html` both with group root. Is any way to run this script under php ?

Comment: What returns the statement `echo shell_exec("sh test.sh 2>&1");`?

Comment: cannot create /dev/ttyUSB0: Permission denied test.sh: 5: cannot create /dev/ttyUSB0: Permission denied test.sh: 6: cannot create /dev/ttyUSB0: Permission denied. OK Thank u :)

Comment: The user executing the PHP does not have permission to write to /dev/ttyUSB0. What the shell command `ls -l /dev/ttyUSB0` returns?

Comment: `crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 0 Mar 13 13:26 /dev/ttyUSB0`

Comment: Then you could add a user that runs PHP to the group `dialout` with `usermod -a -G dialout <username>`. "dialout: Full and direct access to serial ports." so you have to assess the security considerations in your use case.

Comment: I will do this and let u know, dzieki